Self-hosted dashboard service for glueing together pre-made Vega plots
I'm using the Vega visualization grammar to build custom diagrams.
Some of these diagrams have interactive elements (e.g. sliders and checkboxes) using Vega's bind parameters.
I'd like to embed our existing Vega diagrams as "templates" into a ...

self-hosted
open-source
webservice

... that allows users to:

Create concrete diagrams from our templates, by swapping out their data source.¹ The data source could be simply an URL, which Vega queries.
Create their own templates by specifying a Vega-description.json.
Create custom dashboards from multiple concrete diagrams, e.g. drag and drop them into a "canvas" where they can be resized and repositioned.
Store their dashboards in our webservice.
Embed their dashboards from our webservice in other websites.

It would be nice if the webservice could also store values for parameters, especially those that use bind. E.g. When a user adds a diagram with a slider to their dashboard, the altered value of that slider can be stored as the new default for whenever the dashboard is opened.
¹ Note that the requirement about swapping out data sources can be implicitly satisfied by the ability to store default values for parameters, as the data source itself can be a parameter: "data": [{"url": {"signal": "datasourceParameter"}, ….
It would also be good if the webservice had user accounts. The main benefit of having multiple users would be to prevent one user from accidentally altering dashboards of other users. Read-only access to everything is fine though, meaning the embedding feature does not have to deal with permissions.
Is there any simple tool for managing (Vega) dashboards?
Writing plugins for a more general dashboard tool could be ok too, if above usecases are simple to implement. E.g. there has to be a workflow for templates already.
I looked at bigger tools like Grafana or Elasticsearch Kibana. It seems possible to write plugins for these, that just render our custom diagrams; the latter even has a plugin for rendering Vega already. However, neither do we want to use the databases associated with those tools for our own diagrams, nor do we want to use the default widgets in those tools. Our usecase (visualizing discrete data) is too far off from their main focus (visualizing timeseries data).
Setting up these tools, and configuring them to integrate with our usecase, seems like a lot of overhead for a half-baked solution. But that's just my first impression -- if I'm just not knowledgeable enough about these tools, please correct me.
